# Find the number of XML Elements in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery

I have a table with `ID (Primary key)` and `XML data type` in `SQL Server 2008`.

I need help to find the ID where its associated XML has more than 500 Elements (Parents and child will be considered as 2 separated elements)

I have about 15,000 records in that table.

Comment: Can you provide an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your table? Then it's very likely you will get an answer matching exactly your needs.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very interesting question. I suggest you create a function that returns children count of current node and then reassigns each child to be root (@x1) and calls itself while it gets 0 (no more children) like example below, but concurrent.
Found this article where it shows how to traverse XML
http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Traverse-Hierarchical-XML/

```
DECLARE    @x1 XML
SELECT @x1 = '
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Jacob</Name>
    <Number>1001</Number>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Number>1002</Number>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <Number>1003</Number>
  </Employee>
    </Employees>'

SELECT
    @x1.value('count(/*/*)','INT') AS ChildrenOfRootElement
```

Sorry I don't have SQL Management studio atm so can't test it or produce function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID
from YourTable 
where XMLCol.value('count(//*)', 'int') > 500
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/121a5/1)